Caching Django Rest Framework function-based view causes permission classes to be ignored
I'm having a strange issue where my function-based view caching seems to be conflicting with the permission classes applied to it. The decorators for the view are as follows:
@cache_page(3600)
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((APIKeyPermission,))
def function_based_view(request): 
    # function-based view code here...

The problem is: When I try to access the view via HTTP GET, if it is not yet cached, it will require the APIKeyPermission to be satisfied and give an 401 error. This is correct behavior. Once the view has been successfully cached, any HTTP GET request can successfully access the view without providing any required permissions. It is important to note that once the view is cached, the @permission_classes decorator seems to do nothing and the view does not even fall back to the DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES as specified in settings.py (which in this case are even more strict than the single permission class specified in the @permission_classes method decorator.)
In short: Once the view is cached, it can be accessed without any of the permission classes being applied to it.
How do I fix this so that the permission classes are properly applied to cached views?

Would it work for you if you change it like?

or remove @permission_classes((APIKeyPermission,)) and code it however you wanted to be cached?

I was able to find a solution related to the ordering of the decorators. Thank you for your contributions though.

I feel a bit foolish for having asked this question now, because I was able to find the answer myself pretty quickly. The order of the decorators seems to matter. Re-ordering them as follows has fixed the issue:
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((APIKeyPermission,))
@cache_page(3600)
def function_based_view(request): 
    # function-based view code here...

It still surprises me that no permissions classes were being applied though. It seems problematic that there is apparently a scenario where neither the defaults nor the overridden permission classes are used. I was certainly under the impression that that would never happen.
